# Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: onAdd is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-context

[image: 2]

I am trying to use `onAdd` function but it is showing this error as show in image. Should I have to define this function in any other way or is there any error in the definition of `onAdd` function? Please help.

Also I am following this project to learn next.js :-
https://github.com/adrianhajdin/ecommerce_sanity_stripe

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { toast } from 'react-hot-toast';

const Context = createContext();

export const StateContext = ({ children }) => {
  const [showCart, setShowCart] = useState(false);
  const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]);
  const [totalPrice, setTotalPrice] = useState(0);
  const [totalQuantities, setTotalQuantities] = useState(0);
  const [qty, setQty] = useState(1);

  let foundProduct;
  let index;

  const onAdd = (product, quantity) => {
    const checkProductInCart = cartItems.find((item) => item._id === product._id);
    
    setTotalPrice((prevTotalPrice) => prevTotalPrice + product.price * quantity);
    setTotalQuantities((prevTotalQuantities) => prevTotalQuantities + quantity);
    
    if(checkProductInCart) {
      const updatedCartItems = cartItems.map((cartProduct) => {
        if(cartProduct._id === product._id) return {
          ...cartProduct,
          quantity: cartProduct.quantity + quantity
        }
      })

      setCartItems(updatedCartItems);
    } else {
      product.quantity = quantity;
      
      setCartItems([...cartItems, { ...product }]);
    }

    toast.success(`${qty} ${product.name} added to the cart.`);
  } 

  const onRemove = (product) => {
    foundProduct = cartItems.find((item) => item._id === product._id);
    const newCartItems = cartItems.filter((item) => item._id !== product._id);

    setTotalPrice((prevTotalPrice) => prevTotalPrice -foundProduct.price * foundProduct.quantity);
    setTotalQuantities(prevTotalQuantities => prevTotalQuantities - foundProduct.quantity);
    setCartItems(newCartItems);
  }

  const toggleCartItemQuanitity = (id, value) => {
    foundProduct = cartItems.find((item) => item._id === id)
    index = cartItems.findIndex((product) => product._id === id);
    const newCartItems = cartItems.filter((item) => item._id !== id)

    if(value === 'inc') {
      setCartItems([...newCartItems, { ...foundProduct, quantity: foundProduct.quantity + 1 } ]);
      setTotalPrice((prevTotalPrice) => prevTotalPrice + foundProduct.price)
      setTotalQuantities(prevTotalQuantities => prevTotalQuantities + 1)
    } else if(value === 'dec') {
      if (foundProduct.quantity > 1) {
        setCartItems([...newCartItems, { ...foundProduct, quantity: foundProduct.quantity - 1 } ]);
        setTotalPrice((prevTotalPrice) => prevTotalPrice - foundProduct.price)
        setTotalQuantities(prevTotalQuantities => prevTotalQuantities - 1)
      }
    }
  }

  const incQty = () => {
    setQty((prevQty) => prevQty + 1);
  }

  const decQty = () => {
    setQty((prevQty) => {
      if(prevQty - 1 < 1) return 1;
     
      return prevQty - 1;
    });
  }

  return (
    <Context.Provider
      value={{
        showCart,
        setShowCart,
        cartItems,
        totalPrice,
        totalQuantities,
        qty,
        incQty,
        decQty,
        onAdd,
        toggleCartItemQuanitity,
        onRemove,
        setCartItems,
        setTotalPrice,
        setTotalQuantities 
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </Context.Provider>
  )
}

export const useStateContext = () => useContext(Context);
```

The place where I am using onAdd function is this (at the place of ADD TO CART BUTTON ) :--

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { AiOutlineMinus, AiOutlinePlus, AiFillStar, AiOutlineStar } from 'react-icons/ai';

import { client, urlFor } from '../../lib/client';
import { Product } from '../../components';
import { useStateContext } from '../../context/StateContext';

const ProductDetails = ({ product, products }) => {
  const { image, name, details, price } = product;
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  const { decQty, incQty, qty, onAdd, setShowCart } = useStateContext();

  const handleBuyNow = () => {
    onAdd(product, qty);

    setShowCart(true);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="product-detail-container">
        <div>
          <div className="image-container">
            <img src={urlFor(image && image[index])} className="product-detail-image" />
          </div>
          <div className="small-images-container">
            {image?.map((item, i) => (
              <img 
                key={i}
                src={urlFor(item)}
                className={i === index ? 'small-image selected-image' : 'small-image'}
                onMouseEnter={() => setIndex(i)}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="product-detail-desc">
          <h1>{name}</h1>
          <div className="reviews">
            <div>
              <AiFillStar />
              <AiFillStar />
              <AiFillStar />
              <AiFillStar />
              <AiOutlineStar />
            </div>
            <p>
              (20)
            </p>
          </div>
          <h4>Details: </h4>
          <p>{details}</p>
          <p className="price">${price}</p>
          <div className="quantity">
            <h3>Quantity:</h3>
            <p className="quantity-desc">
              <span className="minus" onClick={decQty}><AiOutlineMinus /></span>
              <span className="num">{qty}</span>
              <span className="plus" onClick={incQty}><AiOutlinePlus /></span>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div className="buttons">
            <button type="button" className="add-to-cart" onClick={() => onAdd(product, qty)}>Add to Cart</button>
            <button type="button" className="buy-now" onClick={handleBuyNow}>Buy Now</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="maylike-products-wrapper">
          <h2>You may also like</h2>
          <div className="marquee">
            <div className="maylike-products-container track">
              {products.map((item) => (
                <Product key={item._id} product={item} />
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const query = `*[_type == "product"] {
    slug {
      current
    }
  }
  `;

  const products = await client.fetch(query);

  const paths = products.map((product) => ({
    params: { 
      slug: product.slug.current
    }
  }));

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: 'blocking'
  }
}

export const getStaticProps = async ({ params: { slug }}) => {
  const query = `*[_type == "product" && slug.current == '${slug}'][0]`;
  const productsQuery = '*[_type == "product"]'
  
  const product = await client.fetch(query);
  const products = await client.fetch(productsQuery);

  console.log(product);

  return {
    props: { products, product }
  }
}

export default ProductDetails
```

Comment: Please add the cod in witch you are trying to use `onAdd`

Comment: I have just added that section as well please go through it.